# Python numpy can't be imported from a module?

Tags: python, python-import

My program is just:

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros(2)
```

It's in a folder with a `__init__.py`

If I run it as `python a.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    np.zeros(2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zeros'
```

If I remove `__init__.py`, it works.  The only line in `__init__.py` is an assignment to `__all__`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have a `numpy` folder inside your folder or something with `numpy` name? Try - `import numpy as np; print(np.__file__)` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Oh, of course!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably have a folder with the name ``numpy`that is masking the library`numpy` . You should not name your files/folders such that they mask the library modules.

My guess is this `__init__.py` was inside the folder named `numpy` , when you rmeoved it, Python stopped recognizing it as a package, and hence the correct `numpy` module was loaded.